# Mouse will not appear on monitor 2

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, cursor

I have 3 monitors set up on a lap top docking station. One of the screens is the laptop and 2 additional monitors.  All 3 are working, I think but I can't get the mouse pointer on the 2nd screen

Answer (score 1):

Rightclick your desktop, and select screen resolution.

Look at the image and see where each screen is located. Chances are that the 2nd screen is physically on the left, while in windows it is on the right.

Drag and drop this screen to where it is in real life, hit apply, then ok, and try again. This should solve it for you.